# canGoBack in WebView always false in android

Tags: android, kotlin, url, webview

> I have implemented Viewpager and TabLayout in an app. And one of the tab has a **BasketRootFragment** .It has a WebViewFragment

```
class BasketRootFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var basketFrag: WebViewFragment
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_basket_root, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun setMenuVisibility(menuVisible: Boolean) {
        super.setMenuVisibility(menuVisible)
        if(menuVisible) {
            if(::basketFrag.isInitialized.not()){
                childFragmentManager.commit(allowStateLoss = true) {
                    val urlString = RemoteConfigRepository.getString(RemoteKey.url_basket).addBaseUrl()
                    val basketTabTitle = RemoteConfigRepository.getString(RemoteKey.trans_tab_basket)
                    basketFrag = WebViewFragment.forBasket(Triple(Screen.BASKET, basketTabTitle, urlString))
                    replace(R.id.fragment_container_view, basketFrag, WebViewFragment.TAG)
                    addToBackStack(WebViewFragment.TAG)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun goBackInWeb(): Boolean = basketFrag.goBackInWeb()
    fun canGoBackInWeb(): Boolean = basketFrag.canGoBackInWeb()
    fun reload(restCaller: RestCaller) = basketFrag.reload(restCaller)
}
```

when another link opens from that webView I handle it below like

```
private fun shouldOverrideUrl(webView: WebView?, url: String): Boolean {
if(isBasketFragment() && url.isBasketUrl().not()){
    webView?.loadUrl(url)
    return true
}
   return false
}
```

> On click of any item inside I return true for `shouldOverrideUrl` but when checking below function

```
if(binding.webview.canGoBack()) { // it is always false.
    binding.webview.goBack()
}
```

Comment: I was returning false and not handling . that's why canGoBack is false. I have to call webView?.loadUrl(url) and return true  In order to catach webview.canGoBack

Answer (score 0):

The relevant page in your webview history may not have been loaded. That's why `canGoBack()` always returns `false`.

> **canGoBack()** : Gets whether this WebView has a back history item.

In your scenario I would suggest checking the web view history.The method you should use for this is

```
copyBackForwardList()
```

Example usage

```
yourWebView.copyBackForwardList().run {
    (0 until currentIndex).forEach { 
        Log.d("URL at index $it", getItemAtIndex(it).url)
    }
}
```

Of course, I recommend using this for testing purposes only. In short, I don't think there is a webview history. That's why `canGoback` always returns `false`.